# while loop for checking if input mathces the criteria

Tags: python, while-loop

I have to use the while loop for creating following function:

```
def ask_user(age_limit: int) -> int:
```

Ask a user their age using input("What is your age?").

This process must be repeated until a correct age is entered.

The age is correct if:

- it is numeric -> otherwise print "Wrong input!" and ask to put the input age again
- it is greater or equal to the age_limit -> otherwise print "Too young!" and ask to put the
  input age again
- it is less or equal to 100 -> otherwise print "Too old!" and ask to put the input age again

If the age is correct, the function returns the correct age as an integer.

An example (with age_limit 18):

```
What is your age? a
Wrong input!
What is your age? 10
Too young!
What is your age? 101
Too old!
What is your age? 21
(function returns 21)
```

I am a beginner in Python and I do not know how to write this code.

I have tried:

```
def ask_user_age(age_limit: int) -> int:

    age = int(input("What is your age?"))
    while True:
        if not age.isdigit:
            print("Wrong input!")
        elif int(age) < age_limit:
            print("Too young!")
        elif int(age) > 100:
            print("Too old!")
    else:
        return age
```

But this does not work! Please help me :)

Comment: forget about the function part for a minute, and just make a loop that works...  In your "while loop" you will need to ask again for the next guess, so add that...  and then figure out how to get out of the loop if the guess is correct

Comment: The `else:` block needs to be indented so it's inside the `while` loop.

Comment: `isdigit` is a function, you need to call it: `age.isdigit()`

Comment: You must not call `int()` when reading the input. You can't do that until after you check `age.isdigit()`.

Comment: Thank you for all these comments, it all makes sense and of course very valid points, I don´t understand how I did not notice these mistakes myself :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to move the `input()` call inside the loop, so you get a new age if any of the validation checks fail.

You need to add `()` after `isdigit` to call the function.

`else: return age` needs to be inside the loop. Otherwise, the loop never ends.

```
def ask_user_age(age_limit: int) -> int:
    while True:
        age = input("What is your age?")
        if not age.isdigit():
            print("Wrong input!")
        elif int(age) < age_limit:
            print("Too young!")
        elif int(age) > 100:
            print("Too old!")
        else:
            return age
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def ask_user(age_limit):
while True:
    age = input("What is your age?")
    if not age.isnumeric():
        print("Wrong input!")
    elif int(age) < age_limit:
        print("Too young!")
    elif int(age) > 100:
        print("Too old!")
    elif int(age)==age_limit:
        print(age)
   # For example age limit is 21
   ask_user(21)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).